# How to import a js file in a Chrome extension service worker?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, import, socket.io, service-worker

I am trying to use socket.io library in a service worker of y Chrome extension, but when I try to load it in Chrome I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

I got the library from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js), then I saved the it in my extension folder, in socketIo.js:

[image]

Then in my service_worker.js, I try to import it:

```
import io from './socketIo.js';
const socket = io("http://localhost:3002");
```

Since it as service worker, I do not attach it to my extension html file, therefore I can't simply set the worker as a module like this:

```
<script type="module" src="./service_worker.js"></script>.
```

Also, since extensions are not Node.js applications, they don't have a package.json where I could set the property "type": "module.

And as you can see I used both the relative path and the extension of the file imported, as suggested here: [Chrome Extension Service Worker not Supporting Importing Other JS Files or NPM Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73011178/chrome-extension-service-worker-not-supporting-importing-other-js-files-or-npm-p)

Now I've added the ES module version of socket.io and its "map" file.
And updated my service worker in manifest.json to be a ES module too:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when I tried to load the extension again, I get this warning: "Service worker registration failed. Status code: 3", and the generic error:

[image]

Comment: @KrunalShah Hi, could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since it as service worker, I do not attach it to my extension html
> file, therefore I can't simply set the worker as a module like this: .
>
> Also, since extensions are not Node.js applications, they don't have a
> package.json where I could set the property "type": "module.

[Register the service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#manifest)

> You can optionally specify an extra field of "type": "module" to
> include the service worker as an ES Module, which allows you to import
> further code.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "socket.io",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    }
}
```

But the socket.io version you're using isn't an ES Module:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/socket.io.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

So I downloaded `socket.io.esm.min.js` and `socket.io.esm.min.js.map` from https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.3

I don't know if they have an ES Module version of socket.io 1.7.3

Including the .map file in the extension prevents this error in the service worker console:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://cfdinlnmiepoligakoinbffeaphkfmmp/socket.io.esm.min.js.map:
> System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

background.js

```
import io from "/socket.io.esm.min.js";
const socket = io("http://localhost:3002");
```

The service worker console still gets flooded with this error:

> Event handler of 'beforeunload' event must be added on the initial evaluation
> of worker script.

But I think there's a solution for that on Stackoverflow.

Or not:

- [Add Socket.io to service_worker (chrome extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73845346/19840875)
- [Remote Socket.io Connection not working from a manifest v3 extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160114/remote-socket-io-connection-not-working-from-a-manifest-v3-extension#comment130937819_74160114)

Also, put the libraries `socket.io.esm.min.js` and `socket.io.esm.min.js.map` inside the same folder of service worker, in the same level (not in a sub folder).

After you made this changes, just refresh you extension in chrome://extensions/. But if this doesn't work, delete your extension and load it unpacked again.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMuller ! What is the service worker console?
I made the chages, and when reload my extension in chrome://extensions I get the error that I added up there in my question, but not the "Event handler of 'beforeunload' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script."

Comment: This error disappears when I remove the "import io from "/socket.io.esm.min.js";
const socket = io("http://localhost:3002"); " from my service worker...

Comment: "What is the service worker console?" --- Please read [Debugging extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_debugging/).

Comment: I made the chages, and when reload my extension in chrome://extensions I get the error that I added up there in my question, but not the "Event handler of 'beforeunload' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script." --- It works for me, but if it doesn't for you, then I'm afraid I cannot help. Maybe someone else can. I wish you the best of luck with your extension!

Comment: I had the socket.io files in a subfolder of that of serice_worker.js. So I moved them to the same level, and deleted and added my extension again (refresh was not enough), then it worked.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the ES Modules, as long as the import statement in the service worker uses the correct path. If the ES modules are located at `/esm/socket.io.esm.min.js` and `/esm/socket.io.esm.min.js.map`, then `import io from "/esm/socket.io.esm.min.js";` in the service worker imports them. I used abolute paths because that's less confusing; you don't have to know the path of the importing file.

Comment: Yeah. I know. But my relative paths were right, and even though id did not work. I'm not sure what happened. Maybe is something about how expensions manage imports in service worker.