# How to use socket io in service worker ( background.js ) manifest v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, socket.io, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Just like in V2 i can easily use socket.io in my background.js

- let socket = io.connect(url);
- But now i've to migrate V2 to v3 and I want to use socket but know i'm getting this
  error "Error handling response: ReferenceError: io is not defined"
- Is there any way to use socket io in my service worker (background.js)? Thanks
- Another Question is ---> is socket io versions need to be same on both sides (client and server)?

Comment: See [How to import a js file in a Chrome extension service worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74413670/how-to-import-a-js-file-in-a-chrome-extension-service-worker/74414528#74414528)

Comment: @ThomasMueller  i read this answer but the issue is my socket.io version isn't  ES Module. Version is (2.2.0).

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand obvious things, so please pardon me for asking: Why are you using a socket.io version that's 4 years old?

Comment: @ThomasMueller because it is the requirement of server side, socket.io version is need to be less than 2.2.0. And i can’t make any changes to server side because i have no access to that.

Comment: @AhsanHafeez how did you solved this problem? Haved you?